# Excel VBA Set a Commandbutton Caption from a Userform Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that is on an excel spreadsheet (not in a userform) and I have a userfrom that has a textbox on and would like it to, when I enter a name in the textbox on my userform for it to then set the Caption of my button that is on my excel sheet to what ever is entered in the textbox. I would like to know what code I need to use and where to insert that code?

Hope that make sense, please keep in mind I'm a newbie to this so this is why I am asking where to insert the code

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of button is it - Forms or ActiveX?

Comment: well I was using a Form Button, so I suppose for form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in your userform, assuming a textbox named TextBox1, could be like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   If Len(Me.Textbox1.text) > 0 then
     ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Caption = Me.Textbox1.text
   End If
End Sub
```

or if you want the caption to update as you type:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Len(Me.TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then _
        ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").Caption = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I'm after but like I said I'm a newbie, how do I find the button name for the Form button on my excelsheet?, my button is linked to a module called Button_PLU1 which has a sub Button1() what would I set it to for the button name?

Comment: Hold Ctrl and click the button. You should see its name in the Name box to the left of the formula bar - it's probably "Button 1" by default. I've updated my code based on that assumption. :)

Comment: Thats seems to run with out any errors, I just wondering if I'm asking the right question is the text on the button the caption? because that's Im trying to change

Comment: Yes it is. It should update when the cursor leaves the textbox on the userform (if it's the only control, it will be when you close the form). If you want to see it in real time, you could use the Change event of the textbox instead - I'll add that to the code as an option.

Comment: Second option is exactly what I was after and works perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As you have used "CommandButton" (which is an ActiveX control) yet seemingly heading towards a Form control, I have gone with the 2 methods you will need:

ActiveX:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("YourButton").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = "YourText"`

Forms:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("YourButton").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "YourText"`